# Launching Ruby script with command line flag from VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, process, cmd, flags

This question might seem easy, yet there seems to be a tiny tricky moment I cannot bypass.
In a nutshell, I am launching a ruby/watir web automation script from a VB .NET app. The script can work with webdrivers for IE, FF and Chrome. In case of first two it is simple. In case of Chrome it needs to launch the .rb file with --log-path flag.

Here is my code:

```
        Dim chromeStarter As New ProcessStartInfo(generatedScripts(i))
        Dim args As String = " --log-path=" & testRunPath & "\chromedriver.log"

        If isChrome = True Then
            chromeStarter.Arguments = args
            Process.Start(chromeStarter)
        Else
            Process.Start(chromeStarter)
        End If
```

Problem: Indeed it launches the correct .rb file, yet does not take flag into account.
I tried passing both file name and flag as a single string to Process.Start and it didn't work as well.
Flag works fine when script is manually run from cmd.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Have you checked your `args` string in the debugger?